# How to lappy !is.na() for assigning value R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, na

**Target to fill NA with "-" after the last value in a row**

```
# Like this
   SOURCE  X__2  X__3 X__4 X__5 X__6 X__7  X__8  X__9 INFO
1: 04.xlsx David David    -    -    -    -     -     -    A
2: 05.xlsx  <NA>  <NA>  Tom  Tom    -    -     -     -    B
3: 06.xlsx  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA> Mary Mary     -     -    C
4: 07.xlsx  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> Peter Peter    D

# Sample data
dt <- data.table(SOURCE = c("04.xlsx","05.xlsx","06.xlsx","07.xlsx"),
                   X__2 = c("David",NA,NA,NA),
                   X__3 = c("David",NA,NA,NA),
                   X__4 = c(NA,"Tom",NA,NA),
                   X__5 = c(NA,"Tom",NA,NA),
                   X__6 = c(NA,NA,"Mary",NA),
                   X__7 = c(NA,NA,"Mary",NA),
                   X__8 = c(NA,NA,NA,"Peter"),
                   X__9 = c(NA,NA,NA,"Peter"),
                   INFO = LETTERS[1:4])
```

**My attempt but not works**

```
# Find odd columns 
TAR_COL <- grep("X__",colnames(dt))[!c(TRUE,FALSE)]

dt[!is.na(TAR_COL),(TAR_COL):="-",.SDcols =TAR_COL]
```

**This script works when specifying col ,but lose the ability of choosing columns dynamically**

```
#
dt[!is.na(X__3),(grep("X__3",names(dt))+1):(grep("INFO",names(dt))-1) := "-"][]

  SOURCE  X__2  X__3 X__4 X__5 X__6 X__7  X__8  X__9 INFO
1: 04.xlsx David David    -    -    -    -     -     -    A
```

*As the real dataset is imported from different xlsx data , dynamically choosing the odd number **is a must***

**Are there any method to apply `!is.na()` in vectorized columns index and assign value ?**

Comment: Look at the `TAR_COL`, it is a numeric index, there is no `NA`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `set`.  Loop through the column index of 'TAR_COL', with `set`, specify the column index (`j`) and row index (`i` - where the NA is in that specific column), and set the `value` as '-'

```
for(j in TAR_COL) set(dt, i = which(is.na(dt[[j]])), j= j, value = "-")
dt
#   SOURCE  X__2  X__3 X__4 X__5 X__6 X__7  X__8  X__9 INFO
#1: 04.xlsx David David <NA>    - <NA>    -  <NA>     -    A
#2: 05.xlsx  <NA>     -  Tom  Tom <NA>    -  <NA>     -    B
#3: 06.xlsx  <NA>     - <NA>    - Mary Mary  <NA>     -    C
#4: 07.xlsx  <NA>     - <NA>    - <NA>    - Peter Peter    D
```

Here, the `NA` elements of columns 3, 5, 7, 9 are replaced to `-`

---

NOTE: `!is.na(TAR_COL)` wouldn't help as the 'TAR_COL' is just a column index

#### Update

Based on the clarification from the OP i.e.  replacing NA has to be horizontally from the last appeared value until the last column before "INFO", we can create an index with cumulative sum as @markus suggested in the comments

```
# get the column names that start with 'X__'
nms <- names(dt)[startsWith(names(dt), "X__")]
# change the i index with cumulative sum
for(j in nms) set(dt, i = which(cumsum(!is.na(dt[[j]])) == 0), j = j, value = "-")
```

Comment: Sorry akrun i should better remove the misleading odd column index part in my question, its a great answer but the logic to fill NA has to be horizontally from the last appeared value until the last column before "INFO" column .`dt[!is.na(X__3),(grep("X__3",names(dt))+1):(grep("INFO",names(dt))-1) := "-"][]
dt[!is.na(X__5),(grep("X__5",names(dt))+1):(grep("INFO",names(dt))-1) := "-"][]
dt[!is.na(X__7),(grep("X__7",names(dt))+1):(grep("INFO",names(dt))-1) := "-"][]`  result is the target to achieve like i posted on the top of the question

Comment: @akrun I _think_ OP wants `nms <- names(dt)[startsWith(names(dt), "X__")]; for(j in nms) set(dt, i = which(cumsum(!is.na(dt[[j]])) == 0), j = j, value = "-")`

Comment: @markus Thank you.  Should I include it in the post

Comment: markus , akrun  thank you so much ! Since `set()` for-loop updating rows of certain columns ,`dft[[j]]` to update every variables , `which()` for subsetting , How `cumsum( x == 0 )`  is functioning ? beg for teaching ! (as `!is.na(dt[[j]])` already subsetted NA variables)

Comment: @rane It is loooping through each column (it is `dt[[j]]`) to find the row index.  So, in every iteration, it is a new column and the loop executes only once